# Добавление нового индекса в JSON

Tags: json, node.js

имеется JSON, который читается при загрузке:

```
{
    "1":
    {
        "title":"Ты кто?",
        "buttons":
        {
            "1":
            {
                "answer":"человек",
                "ptrs":"1"
            },
            "2":
            {
                "answer":"кот",
                "ptrs":"4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

нужно добавить еще один индекс, как можно преобразовать это в массив, чтобы после добавить туда еще индекс и записать это обратно в JSON

при обработке json c помощью JSON.parse выдает ошибку Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: _JSON.parse выдает ошибку Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1_ - потому что надо передавать туда строку, а ты передаешь объект.

Comment: @Grundy как можно переконвертировать объект в строку?

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)